# SVG - Center image in circle without image fill

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-filters

I have created a circle in SVG and trying to display image in circle and when the circle size is increased the image is also increasing but I wanted to have image same as it is, changing the circle size without changing the image size, currently its filling in the circle:

Here is the HTML code, can somebody please help

```html
<svg id="graph" width="100%" height="400px">

  <!-- pattern -->
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%"
             viewBox="0 0 512 512">
      <image x="0%" y="0%" width="512" height="512" xlink:href="https://ppcaxis.com/cat-150.jpg"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
    
  <circle id="sd" class="medium" cx="5%" cy="40%" r="5%" fill="url(#image)" stroke="lightblue" stroke-width="0.5%" />
  <circle id="sd2" class="medium" cx="25%" cy="50%" r="10%" fill="url(#image)" stroke="lightblue" stroke-width="0.5%" />
<circle id="sd3" class="medium" cx="25%" cy="80%" r="15%" fill="url(#image)" stroke="lightblue" stroke-width="0.5%" />
</svg>
```

Only challange for me here to NOT resize and fill image in circle.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using SVG for this? Why not HTML?

Comment: Yes I have to use SVG for animation purpose, can't handle those animation using div

Comment: what kind of animation you want, I am pretty sure we can do it with CSS

Comment: Animation kind of thing happening with d3.js that's why I am trying to achieve from svg only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general answer to this question is that you need to use `patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` to make patterns be relative to the current coordinate system, rather than being relative to the object it is applied to.

For example, in the SVG below, I have set the pattern to be 200x200.  Note that it is the same size no matter what the radius of each circle is.  Also, it repeats independently of the siza and position of the circle also.

```html
<svg id="graph" width="100%" height="400px">

  <!-- pattern -->
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" height="200" width="200"
             viewBox="0 0 512 512">
      <image x="0%" y="0%" width="512" height="512" xlink:href="https://ppcaxis.com/cat-150.jpg"></image>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
    
  <circle id="sd" class="medium" cx="5%" cy="40%" r="5%" fill="url(#image)" stroke="lightblue" stroke-width="0.5%" />
  <circle id="sd2" class="medium" cx="25%" cy="50%" r="10%" fill="url(#image)" stroke="lightblue" stroke-width="0.5%" />
<circle id="sd3" class="medium" cx="25%" cy="80%" r="15%" fill="url(#image)" stroke="lightblue" stroke-width="0.5%" />
</svg>
```

So if you wanted each circle to have an independently positioned cat pattern, you would need to define a pattern specifically for each circle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried this but the another approach was to handle using clip path,